# Merge interface from namespace in module declaration file

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I have a javascript library which has a type definition file here: https://github.com/tyranid-org/tyranid/blob/master/tyranid.d.ts which is exposed via the `typings` property in my `package.json` file.

a basic version of the definition file:

```
export default Tyr;

declare namespace Tyr {
  interface Document {
    $save(): Promise<Document>;
  }
}
```

I would like to extend the `Document` interface in a completely separate typescript library: https://github.com/CrossLead/tyranid-gracl which imports `tyranid` along with its typings, by adding a `$newMethod()` method to the document interface. Can this be done?

I've tried the following in a separate declaration file in the second repo, but it doesn't work:

```
import Tyr from 'tyranid';

declare namespace Tyr {

  interface Document {
    $newMethod(): number;
  }

}
```

I can modify both declarations if necessary -- its very possible I am not writing the original type definition file for tyranid correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The following ended up working...

in `node_modules/tyranid/tyranid.d.ts`:

```
export = Tyr // must do "import * as Tyr from 'tyranid'" instead of default

declare namespace Tyr {
  export interface Document {
    // original definition...
  }
}
```

in `mylib/tyranid-extensions.d.ts`...

```
declare module "tyranid" {
  interface Document {
    addedMethod(): boolean; 
  }
}
```

Thanks @pelle-jacobs for the help!

Comment: actually -- this causes further headaches, as the tyranid library itself is structured around a default export for the main module.

Comment: Exactly. My assumption was that you didn't want to change your actual js library. Well `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to augment the module `tyranid`. The general syntax is pretty straightforward: [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/b04e04ca9e4f9671ab5bd7f579a5de9f3ebf3c32/src/index.d.ts#L106) is an example of `redux-thunk` augmenting `redux`.

However, because `tyranid` exports `default`, module augmentation is not fully supported. `export =` has been fixed, as discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6722).

To augment `tyranid`, the best I could come up with (inspired by this [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7148#issuecomment-197528646)), is to throw the `Tyr` namespace into the global scope:

**node_modules/tyranid/tyranid.d.ts**

```
import * as Express from 'express';
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';

export default TyrStatic;

declare global {
  namespace TyrStatic {
    // existing implementation of the Tyr namespace
  }
}
```

**./index.d.ts**

```
declare namespace TyrStatic {
  interface specialInterface {
    someProp: number
  }
}
```

(depending on whether you need this augmentation to use external modules, you might need to wrap it in a [`declare global {}`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules))

**src/app.ts**

```
import Tyr from 'tyranid'
let specialVariable: Tyr.specialInterface = { someProp: 4 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help! It looks like I get the error "Module augmentation cannot introduce new names in the top level scope." when following that format though -- any ideas? example here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20default%20Test%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20global%20%7B%0D%0A%09namespace%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D