# Augment external module that exports default

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I augment a module that exports default? Eg:

**default-module.d.ts**

```
declare namespace TheNamespace {
  interface TheInterface {
    prop: number
  }
}

export default TheNamespace
```

**app.ts**

```
import theModule from "./default-module"

declare module "./default-module" {
  interface AugmentedInterface {
    augmentedProp: number
  }
}

let theNormalVariable: theModule.TheInterface          // fine
let theAugmentedVariable: theModule.AugmentedInterface // errors
```

However, when your `export =` instead of `export default`, this seems to work fine. (as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6722))

**equals-module.d.ts**

```
declare namespace TheNamespace {
  interface TheInterface {
    prop: number
  }
}

export = TheNamespace
```

**app.ts**

```
import theModule = require("./equals-module")

declare module "./equals-module" {
  interface AugmentedInterface {
    augmentedProp: number
  }
}

let theNormalVariable: theModule.TheInterface          // fine
let theAugmentedVariable: theModule.AugmentedInterface // fine
```

Comment: as a futher example, the answer here works if you keep `export =`, but fails if you use `export default`... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39193323/1718488