# Merging interface from @types/xxx repositories

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There are some cases when in @types/xxx repositories are missing or invalid types.

i.e. @types/restify needs to add [key: string]: string; to Server class / interface.

I tried to create own typings in my project in file 'restify.d.ts' with content

```
declare module 'restify' {
  namespace restify {
    inteface Server {
      [key: string]: string;
    }
   }
 }
```

When I import module in a file by:

```
import { Server } from 'restify';
```

All defined types by @types/restify are completely wiped and compiler does not recognized them. It seems that instead of merge it replaced everything.
Is there any way how to merge types in @types/... repositories in projects?

EDIT: Ofc, from long perspective I send pull but till this time I cannot stop local dev - so, in my case it is basicaly a hotfix.

Comment: Just as a side note: In the long run it would be better to update the definition at DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/restify/index.d.ts so that the npm types package gets updated.

Comment: You could copy the current definition file from @types/xxx to your project and update it. As far as I know you just have to update tsconfig.json to contain the location in `{"compilerOptions": {"paths": {"restify": ["./path/to/index"]}}}` (without d.ts extension)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to directly edit the @types/restify d.ts file locally.

Additionally, you might want to try adding a [triple slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) referencing @types/restify at the top of your d.ts file. You may also want to consider the options described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185728/merge-interface-from-namespace-in-module-declaration-file).