# How to let TypeScript know about my Object.defineProperty() Extension

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I'm working on a Canvas with the Konva library and I needed this extension on the Konva.Line prototype (because you only get relative y of Lines, even if using getAbsolutePositon()):

```
Object.defineProperty(Konva.Line.prototype, "absY", {
    value: function()  {
        return this.getSelfRect().y + this.y()
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
```

This already works, but the ".absY()"-Call is always red in my IDE (WebStorm), because TypeScript doesn't know about this type.

How can I fix this inside a SveteKit Project?

I heard, It's not a good practice to do this, but I'm spoiled by Kotlin

I already tried to add

```
declare namespace Konva {
    interface Line {
        absY: () => number;
    }
}
```

to the app.d.ts, but it doesn't help and it says "Unused interface Line" from the IDE

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `defineProperty` instead of just extending the `prototype` directlry. Also, why do you have `writable: true`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know exactly. I got this snipped from the internet: But I tried without writable now, and it works too, so thank you :)

Comment: Someone should post that as an answer.

Comment: No, I wasn't clear sorry. I could remove "writable: true", and that's why I thanked. But the original issue is still there

Comment: Is `Konva` (the one where you access `Konva.Line`) a global, or imported from some module? A `declare`tion is definitely the way to go

Comment: Konva is a npm module. I import it via "import Konva from 'konva'". Does this answer your question? As you can see, I'm new to Web Dev :)

Comment: Do we need to know about "Konva" to answer this?  You can't [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) a default export, so if that's what `Konva` is, it might not be possible.  It has to be a named export.  Could you provide a [mre] that shows what's happening in a standalone IDE?

Comment: You need to wrap it into `declare module "konva" {} `. But it's `export default namespace`, it if that's possible at all. I guess you need to `declare module "konva/shapes/line" { export interface`, that should work

Comment: https://github.com/konvajs/konva/blob/master/src/index-types.d.ts is where this type reexported

Comment: Thank you @Dimava I tried declare module "konva", and "Line" wasn't indicated as unused anymore. But It still says "Svelte: Property  absY  does not exist on type  Line<LineConfig>" when I hover over .absY() calls.

I tried your second declare statement, but it als has no effect and "Line" shows as "unused"

Comment: I added "declare module "konva" {
    export interface Line {
        absY: () => number;
    }
}" to anoter .d.ts file, and now Konva.Line(), Konva.Rect(). etc. are red and the IDE says: "Svelte: Property  Line  does not exist on type  typeof import("konva") "

So something is happening  But not enough

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185728/merge-interface-from-namespace-in-module-declaration-file/39193323#39193323 also had this problem

Comment: Seems like it's only possible by manipulating the node_module... well then I would rather just extend the class instead 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to extend the Konva `Line` class to add your custom property.

```
import Konva from 'konva';

// extend the Konva `Line` class
class MyCustomKonvaLine extends Konva.Line {
    public absY() {
        return this.getSelfRect().y + this.y()
    }
}

// sample usage
const greenLine = new MyCustomKonvaLine({
    points: [5, 70, 140, 23, 250, 60, 300, 20],
    stroke: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineJoin: 'round',
    dash: [33, 10]
});

// print the absY value
console.log('greenLine absY equals:', greenLine.absY());

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();

layer.add(greenLine);
stage.add(layer);
```

Not that I know Svelte nor Konva.

Comment: Well, this is possible too of course and would be my Plan B. But I'm just curious how it would work with defineProperty, as I like this concept of extension functions in general.

Comment: @Helyon to satisfy your curiosity, TypeScript cannot work with `defineProperty`, because `defineProperty` changes the shape of the class at runtime. An ugly workaround in this case is that you need to explicitly define a new type after doing `defineProperty`. But then you'll be burdened with the responsibility of making sure that the new type actually represents the object type at runtime. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the definition *where it's defined*
https://tsplay.dev/m3Vl1N

```
declare module "konva/lib/shapes/Line.js" {
  export interface Line {
    foo: "bar"
  }
}

import Konva from "konva"
let line = new Konva.Line()
let bar = line.foo
//  ^?
// let bar: "bar"
```

---

You *cannot* modify `export default namespace`, if this interface wouldn't be exported elsewhere this wouldn't be possible

Comment: Okay this seems to work inside a .ts file. But not inside the <script> tag of svelte :D. I also tried to declare in a separate .ts or d.ts file and import it, but it doesn't work either. If this can be solved, it would be interesting for other svelte users. 

But slowly I realize, it becomes more dirty than a simple class extend

Comment: @Helyon this should be in "global" (no export) `d.ts`, same as any other extension

Comment: There is a app.d.ts file in the src root of a sveltekit project. I tried to add it to this file aswell as to a new d.ts file in the same folder where I use it.